# I am not able to Insert data in my table using MSCK repair

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My problem statement is to move data from one s3 bucket to other s3 bucket and i need to do this for almost 5000 tables that are having data at multiple partitions, there is all the permissions okay that are required for moving data from one bucket to other.

Also, this is my first problem of writing any script.

I was able to write the move command and then i created a function that helped me to create table in the other bucket, however when i am trying to run the mcsk command its not adding data to the tables.

Below is the function that i wrote.

```
import sys
import subprocess
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/spark/"
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/spark/python/")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
 
#create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

 
#input parameter
src_s3_path="s3://aws-a0122-use1-00-p-s3b-p/emrfs/warehouse/octopoda_dw.db/"
tgt_s3_path="s3://aws-a0122-use1-00-p-s3b-g/warehouse/octopoda_dw.db/"
location="location 's3://aws-a0122-use1-00-p-s3b-g/warehouse/octopoda_dw.db/'"
 
 
#data distionary-It contains file names and tables names
table_info=['script_test']
cycl_time_id_list=[202401]
def move_to_s3(table_info):
    for key in sorted(table_info):
        for cycl_time_id in cycl_time_id_list:
            move='aws s3 mv '+src_s3_path+key+'/cycl_time_id='+str(cycl_time_id)+'/ '+tgt_s3_path+key+'_golden'+'/cycl_time_id='+str(cycl_time_id)+'/ --recursive'
            subprocess.call(move, shell=True)
            move='aws s3 mv '+src_s3_path+key+'/CYCL_TIME_ID='+str(cycl_time_id)+'/ '+tgt_s3_path+key+'_golden'+'/CYCL_TIME_ID='+str(cycl_time_id)+'/ --recursive'
            subprocess.call(move, shell=True)
    print("Data Moved successfully")

 
def show_create_table_function(table_info):
    flag=0
    for table in table_info:
        db=spark.sql('use octopoda_dw')
        subprocess.call(db, shell=True)
        command= spark.sql('show create table octopoda_dw.'+table).collect()
        command=str(command)
        command=command.strip()
        command=command.replace(table,table+'_golden')
        command=command.replace('[','')
        command=command.replace(']','')
        command=command.replace('Row(createtab_stmt="','')
        command=command.replace('CREATE TABLE','')
        command=command.replace("`","")
        command=command.replace(" \n" ," ")
        command=command.replace('\\n',' ')
        command=command.replace('n\\',' ')
        command=command.replace("\ ","")
        command=command.replace(" \ ","")
        command=command.replace('")','')

        create=spark.sql("create table if not exists"+command+location)
        subprocess.call(create, shell=True)
        flag=1
        if (flag==1):
            print('Table Created Sucessfully')
        else:
            print('Table Could not be created')
            
    return 0

def mcsk_repair(table_info)

    for table in table_info:
        flag=0
        ins=spark.sql('msck repair table octopoda_dw.'+table+'_golden')
        subprocess.call(ins, shell=True)
        flag=1
        if (flag==1):
            print("Data Inserted Successfully")
        else:
            print("Data could not be inserted")
    return 0
  
if __name__== "__main__":
    move_to_s3(table_info)
    show_create_table_function(table_info)
    mcsk_repair(table_info)
```

Comment: do you need to run aws s3 move commands and then create table and run msck repair statements? I dont know why MSCK REPAIR is not working, but does the create table have the "CYCL_TIME_ID" in upper case defined as a partition column?

I would rather just do a spark.sql(CREATE TABLE AS...) and loop through the tables - let me know if you want sample code for that, but that would just be one step.

Comment: when you say , you would do a spark.sql(CREATE TABLE AS .....) you mean that you would create a table directly in other bucket , like create table t1 as select * from t2 , if yes then how this would be possible as both the tables are in different bucket . Additionally , bucket1 as the schema present in it while the 2nd bucket is not having the required schema , so i was first trying to create that schema in the other bucket by iterating over all the tables

Comment: yes, this will copy the table to the new location and create a table definition on top of it. new location can have another bucket name or same bucket name, you can also use this to copy from one format to another if needed. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html

Comment: thank you so much for putting efforts and helping out